# How can I get more user information after allowing user sign up through Facebook in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I'm using `Python-social-auth`(https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) for user signing up through `Facebook`.

Only defect is that I can't get more information about user if user sign up through `Facebook`. For example, `birth`, `job`, `hobby` are required field but `Facebook` doesn't give these information.

What I want to know is here :

1. In case of `birth`, `Facebook` could give this information. Is there any way to do this? Do I have to edit the code of `Python-social-auth`?
2. I heard that there is a case where after signing up through `Facebook`, let new window show up for getting more infos about users. I want to see example site and how to do this.

Need helps. Thanks.

## Edit

This is what I talked about. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/multiple-providers?locale=en_US#postfb)

> Adding manual login info to a Facebook Login created account
>
> This situation occurs when someone creates their account in your app using Facebook Login, but later wants to also log in to the account using a unique credential and a password. For example, Netflix has a web app that uses Facebook Login alongside a regular login system, and also an Xbox 360 app where people can only use the regular login system.
>
> 1. Ensure the Facebook Login email address is verified
>
> If you use an email address as the unique credential which identifies each account, your app should verify that the email address associated with the person's Facebook account (and obtained during Facebook Login) is valid. You can do this by creating code in your app to send a verification email to the address obtained after Facebook Login (you will probably need to have this step as part of your regular login system anyway).
>
> 2. Ask the person to supply a new password (and other credentials)
>
> Once the email address is verified, you can now request that the person supplies a password, indicating to them that they can use this to log in to your app in future in conjunction with their email address. Once supplied, you can add this to the same part of your database where you are currently storing account information.
>
> If your app's login system doesn't use an email address as the identification and uses something user-generated like a username instead, then you should also request that the person supplies this at the same time as a password.

I want to see example site about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Define in settings `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS` with fields that interest you

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'fields': 'first_name, last_name, birthday'
}
```

List of available fields you can see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user).

Comment: Thanks but what about the information not included in those fields?

Comment: You can only get what API gives.